# Nominal data with large sample being separate out into 3 categories. What type of statistical test can be used?

Tags: categorical-data

So im working on a research proposal for a college class. I have a large sample of about 300-500. The objects in the sample will separated into 3 categories. I'm looking for some type of test that determines if the difference in amounts between groups is significant.

Ex.
Say
Group 1 ended up with 145
Group 2 ended up with 95
Group 3 with 60.

What types of test can be done to determine if the differences are significant and are there any test to determine that these are the likely results of the larger population.

Comment: Significant - compared to what? You'll need a null hypothesis (e.g. that the group sizes are equal). Is that the one you're assuming here?

Comment: Regarding the Null hypothesis, yes. The null would be that they sizes should be equal.

Regarding the significant part. Id say are sizes significantly different compared to one another and would we see that level of difference in the overall population.

Comment: Neat, thanks for the extra info. A chi-squared test is pretty typical for this situation.

Comment: Awesome thank you.

Comment: Please add new info in comments as an edit to the post, so all information is in one place!

Comment: Just to expand on the answer, I think you meant statistical significance while comparing differences, which is useful to determine if p-value is small enough to say that the noise is not the reason for such difference. If p-value is large then it's probably a noise, which breaks null hypothesis. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

You can use the [chi-squared test](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/default2.aspx) here. It compares the expected frequency of events to the observed frequency. Based on your null hypothesis from our discussion in the comments, your expected counts are 100, 100, and 100. From the test, you can get a p-value.